# how to save a cropped image with ember js or javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I tried Jcrop(http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Download.html) and tried to crop an image from my local folder.I was able to preview the cropped image.but not able to find a way to save the resized image.I am using ember js for my web application can any one please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [filesaver.js library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to do that (only supported in several browsers)

Example:

Say you have the cropped image on a canvas. Then you should do:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("thumb-canvas");
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    saveAs(blob, "pretty image.png");
});
```

Note: Again the [`toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) method is not supported in all browsers. For compatibility consider using [canvas-ToBlob](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js)